# How can I build an executable file that is safe from virus attacks? ("Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml" is bothering me)

Tags: c++, security, antivirus

Recently I have completed a chrome extension program.
This program is software compiled in the windows environment.
However, when I tried to run this program, Windows defender gave me a warning saying `Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml` and couldn't run it.

So I tried to find the answer on google and found a great answer on stackoverflow.com.
It could be a false alarm from Virus Protecter, so report it to the AV company.
But I want to solve this problem programatically in my program more safely. In short, I want AV programs to believe that my programs are safe.
Of course, my program is not Virus, it is a safe program.
How can I do it?

Comment: Think about this, if you could do that, then what would stop the virus writers doing the same?

Comment: You might get some more helpful advice if you explained what your Chrome extension is doing. Some virus checkers are heuristic, they look for certain dubious behaviours from software and flag them as harmful even though they may not be.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Title is somethign different from what you are asking. You are trying to fool your antivirus into not reporting something that it now considers as a virus attack.